# Is doing two things on one line always a bad practice?

Tags: c, loops

```
int *itPins = pins;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(itPins);
    itPins++;
}
```

I have the impression that doing two things in one line is bad practice. This is why I am advancing the iterator outside of the only statement, using it. However, I feel blindly following a rule.

- Is this code less error-prone than if the `++` is inside the function invocation?
- Why?
- Does this rule apply to such ultra-simple cases or is it meaningful only for more complex program structures?

Comment: A "side effect" is something non-obvious that a routine does besides yield a return value. But that's not what you're talking about, is it? Your point is whether to pass the counter and advance it in one statement or in two separate statements. That's not a side effect, that's just a question of doing more or less in one line of code.

Comment: I dont think this is an example of "side effects" unless `void ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(T*& pins) { pins++; }` is the function.

Comment: I stand corrected. Changed the title.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie: Unless `ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput` is functionally pure (and therefore pointless), this does show side effects--the question just isn't about that.

Comment: Having an unused counter variable and incrementing something else instead does look like something's wrong to me. `for (int *itPins = pins; itPins < pins + count; itPins++)`.

Comment: This is a textbook example of why some companies develop coding standards. To some people, a line of code is clear and consise whilst to others it is unduly terse and hard to read.

Comment: If these two things are very simple and easy to read I would put them on one line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not always bad practice to do multiple things on one line, but it does have a higher risk of making the program appear more complicated that it needs to be.

If I were pedantic, I could argue that in the line `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)`, you are also doing multiple things, but very few people would mark that line as a violation of the rule.

On the other hand, if you had a line like `ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(itPins++);`, then the increment in the argument does increase the complexity as I would have to look twice to be sure that the code is correct and I would probably flag it as needlessly complicated.

---

Another way to write the loop is like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(pins[i]);
}
```

where you rid yourself completely of the issue.

Comment: To my eye, your revised code makes much more sense.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. Most times I would to avoid such things, but in a simple case like this

```
 ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(itPins++);
```

is *very* idiomatic for most programmers with some experience in the C families of programming languages. With some experience in C code reading, it is IMHO as easy to grasp than the two lines of code in your example.

So I would not be too picky about this special case.

Comment: Good point about idiomatic code.

Comment: You raise an interesting point here. There is an argument for making the code easier to read for developers coming from another language. The counter-argument is that you end up with a lowest-common-denominator approach that doesn't always make best use of the built-in language features.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer is not getting more upvotes.

Comment: That makes 2 of us. Talk about casting pearls before swine...

Comment: Does putting the increment statement outside of the function call have any deleterious effects in C?  One would never combine statements in this way in C#, as the only benefit would be one less line of code in exchange for less readability.

Comment: @Vorac Probably because the revised code in the current top answer is clearer than even this one's suggestion.  But I'm +1ing this one instead because it makes a point about idiomatic code, which is more generic an answer and applies to more situations.

Comment: Re:"why not getting more upvotes". While some people might consider this idiomatic, I don't think most people would with regards to passing a variable as a parameter to a function. In the above example, maybe it can legitimately be argued that it is as clear (certainly not more clear). However, once you get beyond 1 statement in the for loop and more than 1 parameter in the function call the above "idiom" becomes far less clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of style, and there is no definitive answer.  There are some C programmers who are more dogmatic and will hate code with multiple statements per line. Almost no one will object to code where each statement is on a separate line. If there are people on your team who hate seeing multiple statements on a line, then just don't do it.  Argue about something more important.  If the team is just you, then suit yourself.

In your specific example, the best answer is to eliminate `i` and directly iterate through the pin numbers:

```
for(int* p = pins; p < pins + count; ++p) {
    ConfigureGpifPinAsGpioOutput(p);
}
```

BTW, there are lots of C programmers who will really hate your quasi-Hungarian naming conventions.